# How do I get the maximum value of raster cells ignoring nodata with gdal_calc?

Tags: gdal, gdal-calc

I have two integer rasters, A and B, with the same dimensions and cell sizes. I want to compare each cell in A with each cell in B and keep the maximum value. In cases where both have nodata, I want the result to be nodata. In cases where one is nodata, I want the result to be the integer value of the one with data.

```
   Raster A                    Raster B
|   1  |   1  |             |   3  |   1  |
|   1  |nodata|             |nodata|   3  |
|nodata|   1  |             |nodata|nodata|
|nodata|   4  |             |nodata|   1  |

--------------------------------------------
                Desired result
               |   3  |   1  |
               |   1  |   3  |
               |nodata|   1  |
               |nodata|   4  |
```

've tried combining them in many different ways using gdal_calc but somehow I can't seem to get the answer I'm looking for. My first instinct was to use numpy.fmax, which states that the NaN value is ignored. But this calculation

```
--calc "numpy.fmax(A,B)"
```

only gives me the results I want in cells where both datasets have a value. A nodata in either results in nodata in the result:

```
              numpy.fmax result
               |   3  |   1  |
               |nodata|nodata|
               |nodata|nodata|
               |nodata|   4  |
```

Perhaps I'm confused about how nodata translates to NaN in numpy? What is a straightforward way to accomplish this with gdal_calc?

Comment: gdal_calc.py appears to work entirely with masked arrays which have a different behaviour under fmax. Even so, I tried replacing A and B with ma.filled(A, nan) and ma.filled(B, nan). The formula parsed but it didn't fix this problem.