# Get maximum value from two raster using gdal_calc.py with option Ignore NoData calculation enabled

Tags: arcgis-desktop, gdal, gdal-calc, cell-statistics

I would like to get maximum value from two raster using gdal_calc.py with option Ignore NoData calculation enabled.

My question is similar to this unsolved problem: [How do I get the maximum value of raster cells ignoring nodata with gdal_calc?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/243161/how-do-i-get-the-maximum-value-of-raster-cells-ignoring-nodata-with-gdal-calc)

If using ArcGIS Desktop, its easy using Cell Statistics within the Spatial Analyst Toolbox with option Ignore NoData calculation enabled/checked. But currently I don't have any access to ArcGIS, only have gdal.

So, is it possible to use gdal for that purpose?